# Why would the Postgres autoincrement counter move forward during Heroku DB failover?

Tags: postgresql

Heroku did automatic failover to a follower DB.

I noticed a gap in some autoincremented primary key columns after that failover. E.g. before the failover, the latest record had ID 117019 and the next record got ID 117052. No records were deleted.

It's not an issue as such, I was just curious what's going on here, and if I may be correct in attributing it to the failover, or if I should look for other explanations.

Answer (score 1):

These gaps are probably the result of failed transactions that were rolled back.

Sequences are not transactional, that is, the sequence won't return the same value again after a rollback.

This is intentional, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html):

> To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, a `nextval` operation is never rolled back; that is, once a value has been fetched it is considered used and will not be returned again. This is true even if the surrounding transaction later aborts, or if the calling query ends up not using the value. [...] Such cases will leave unused “holes” in the sequence of assigned values. Thus, PostgreSQL sequence objects ***cannot be used to obtain “gapless” sequences***.

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying that you think they're due to failed transactions rather than the failover? Or that the failover might involve failed transactions?

Comment: If the failover occurs while data modifications are in progress, these transactions will fail.

Comment: Thank you, Laurenz. The failover was around 3 am, and that gap of 33 IDs that I mentioned was to a record that is only created during business hours as far as I know, so it doesn't seem like this would explain it. But I might well be missing something.

Comment: It could be unrelated. Whenever the transaction that uses the next value from the sequence is aborted, that value is lost. It could be anything that causes a rollback. It is normal and fine for sequence values to get lost, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL serial or identity columns are usual sequence. So, your the sequence can take several values, but some of them are not used.

Comment: Hi Timur. Thank you. I'm afraid I don't understand.